# collect email using hominid/mailchimp rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to collect emails of prospective users of my app. I've created a page with a simple form. My first question is that since I'm not using a db, do I need a model? And secondly, how do I use "form_for" for form generation if I don't need to use a model. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this. First I created a simple form with an email field and submit button in my views (app/views/home.html.erb). I use form tag helper to easily create the form rather than writing my own html: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html. I made sure route the form action to the correct action in my controller. In the controller I use **hominid** to do the subscription, then redirect to the index using redirect_to (':action => home'). That's all it took.